# How to convert custom Query result to JAVA POJO class

Tags: hibernate

I have a complex query which is fetching data from different tables and then it needs to be converted to a JAVA POJO for display. 
I have tried using transformers for this But i get error as "org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException:Could not find setter for ID on class com.db.loud.dto.lem.Feed"

If I change from id to ID( CAPS) my POJO class it works fine. But thats not how java variables are named.

What is wrong here or is there any better way to do it.

Below code from DAO class:

```
    Session session = getSession();
    String sql = "select a.id, a.name, b.id, b.f1, c.f2, c.f3 from table1 a, table2 b, table3 c where ......................................";

    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setString("id", id.toString());
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Feed.class));
    List<LemFeed> list = query.list();
```

Here Feed is my JAVA POJO class:

```
  public class LemFeed implements Serializable{
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String f1;
  private String f2;
  private String f3;
  private String f4;
 }
```

Comment: can you use Hibernate Query Language HQL instead ?

Answer (score 0):

With JPA you can specify an explicit column name (and more) for your mapped POJO field using [`@Column`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html). Example:

```
@Column(name="ID")
private String id;
```

Comment: After changing the field names to caps, it throws error as "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate resultclass: com.db.loud.dto.lem.Feed"

Answer (score 0):

Used AddScalar for the same to resolve the issue.

```
        List<KondorRecord> kondorRecords = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
            .addScalar("facilityId", new LongType())
```